How do I use Github's Secrets in iOS project?
How do I properly use a secret, that is stored in Github Secrets, in my project? I have the following environment setup.

Project + Environment Variables in Schemes
Secrets Added to Github Codespace (Repository Level)
Project Setup to Read Environment Variables from Scheme

private var developmentToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_DEV_TOKEN"]!
private var productionToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_PROD_TOKEN"]!

Previously I had this workflow that would fetch them and create a Secrets.plist but now that I've removed that, and created it as an Environment variable in Xcode, I don't believe that it will actually be able to access the new variables, coming from the environment.
      - name: Setup Secrets
        run: |
          mkdir -p Project/Shared/Utility/Resources
          /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'add MyDevToken string ${{ secrets.MY_DEV_TOKEN }}' Project/Shared/Utility/Resources/Secrets.plist
          /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'add MyProdToken string ${{ secrets.MY_PROD_TOKEN }}' Project/Shared/Utility/Resources/Secrets.plist

So how do I access the environment variable in my workflow, for use in my workflow, and do I need to also duplicate that to my local project somehow?

Hi @xTwisteDx,
Were you able to achieve this? If so, did you come across any useful tutorials or resources that you can share?

Unfortunately, even after having several other devs take a stab at it, no.
